# **line 110, in <module> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, someone at the company left and I was handed this script (which we really need to work). I've never programmed a day in my life.

After some googling and YouTube, I understand the issue to be that somewhere in the code it is trying to string together using + an integer and a string (and this is not allowed).  I cannot figure out where this error is occurring, however. I' know it says line 110.  Below is what is at line 108-125.  Is the issue with the (account + '----' + "ELP CAC Config Selected')???

```
 if stage == 'CAC':
        if fund == 'ELP':
            logNotes(account + ' --- ' + ' ELP CAC Config Selected')
            fileTypes = ['ConsumerAgreement', 'HCOCAC', 'HCODAC']
        elif fund == 'KW':
            logNotes(account + ' --- ' + ' KW CAC Config Selected')
            fileTypes = ['ConsumerAgreement', 'CAC', 'HCOCAC', 'HCODAC']
    elif stage == 'IC':
        logNotes(account + ' --- ' + ' General IC Config Selected')
        fileTypes = ['BuildingPlans', 'SystemPhotos', 'InstallationCompletionCertificate', 'HCOIC']
    elif stage == 'FA':
        if fund == 'Investec':
            logNotes(account + ' --- ' + ' Investec Config Selected')
            fileTypes = ['BOS', 'ConsumerAgreement', 'ConditionalWaiverIC','Conditional WaiverFA']
            fund = 'KW'
        else:
            logNotes(account + ' --- ' + ' General FA Config Selected')
            fileTypes = ['FinalAcceptanceCertificate', 'PTO']
```

Comment: `account` seems to be the only thing being added to a string, it's probably an `int`. Try wrapping it in a `str` call with `str(account)`.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the line of code where the variable `account` is being used for the first time in the file?

Comment: Pretty sure it is `input()` that's causing this @codehitman. Old dev ran with `Py2` and worked fine, OP ran with `Py3` and result is `TypeError`s.

Comment: @Jim I might be misunderstanding what you're saying here. If the old dev used `input()` then they would have to have explicitly entered an `int`/`float` value as a string, otherwise it would have been evaluated as a number and the same error would persist? Surely it's the other way round; old dev ran in `Py3` and OP is trying to use `Py2`?

Comment: @Jim But in Python3 `input()` returns a string so this shouldn't be a problem:  http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html#the-input-function

Comment: @codehitman whoops, mixed them up ;-)

Comment: @Jim So I'm right? Or have I mixed something up?

Comment: Good, I wasn't going mad then @Jim :P In that case CCUnresti15, you should investigate ways of explicitly running in Python 3.x rather than in Python 2.x (which might be happening by default). Since we don't see the whole script or imports etc., the current answer provided might only be a band-aid to one part and you might find the same types of problem coming up over and over.

Comment: The OP really isn't helping here and the fact that this is tagged with `Python 3.x` only makes it more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you cannot "add" a number and a string of characters. Hence, you must first convert the number to its character representation.
Try replacing the code with this:

```
 account_str = str(account)  # Save the converted account string

 if stage == 'CAC':
    if fund == 'ELP':
        logNotes(account_str + ' --- ' + ' ELP CAC Config Selected')
        fileTypes = ['ConsumerAgreement', 'HCOCAC', 'HCODAC']
    elif fund == 'KW':
        logNotes(account_str + ' --- ' + ' KW CAC Config Selected')
        fileTypes = ['ConsumerAgreement', 'CAC', 'HCOCAC', 'HCODAC']
elif stage == 'IC':
    logNotes(account_str + ' --- ' + ' General IC Config Selected')
    fileTypes = ['BuildingPlans', 'SystemPhotos', 'InstallationCompletionCertificate', 'HCOIC']
elif stage == 'FA':
    if fund == 'Investec':
        logNotes(account_str + ' --- ' + ' Investec Config Selected')
        fileTypes = ['BOS', 'ConsumerAgreement', 'ConditionalWaiverIC','Conditional WaiverFA']
        fund = 'KW'
    else:
        logNotes(account_str + ' --- ' + ' General FA Config Selected')
        fileTypes = ['FinalAcceptanceCertificate', 'PTO']
```